# What does ってえ mean in this manga?

Tags: meaning, manga

What does 「ってえ」 mean? The context is that this character steps wrong as he is walking through the sand, and after letting out a moan he says "ってえ..."

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That should be read together with what's uttered immediately before it. So notice the 「いっ」 in the text bubble uttered simultaneously with the onomatopoeia 「ズキッ」 as he sprains his ankle.

Together, that gives you 「いってぇ...」 = 痛い{いたい} (It hurts!)